# PIVOT function in Oracle 11G giving invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I am trying to work on PIVOT function when I write a simple query to get department number and number of employees in that department, I am getting error.

Here is my query

`select deptno
     ,emp_count from 
(
select deptno from EMPLOYEE
)
PIVOT
( COUNT(name) 
  for deptno in('10','20','30')
);`

I am getting following error

`ORA-00904: "NAME": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"`

this is my table

[image]

Can any one help me in writing and understanding of PIVOT function in SQL query.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle? (Their pivot's aren't the same.)

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images, or links to images.

Comment: @jarlh Okay , I will put in formatted text from next, I am using Oracle, the pic is from tool SQL developer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax of your query is not right. The proper way to write it would be as shown below.
Note that I have used aliases of the form `emp_count_?` ; you can modify it as per you need.

```
SELECT
   * 
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         deptno,
         name 
      FROM
         employee 
   )
   PIVOT (COUNT(name) FOR deptno IN
   (
      '10' AS emp_count_10,
      '20' AS emp_count_20,
      '30' AS emp_count_30
   )
);
```

Comment: Thanks Kaushik , I just tried COUNT(*) it worked . thank you. I got some Idea on PIVOT how to write.